# cannot convert value of type 'UILabel!' to expected argument 'type inout String'

Tags: ios, swift

When I try to increase `currentNumberAdmin` I get:

> cannot convert value of type 'UILabel!' to expected argument 'type in out String'

```
class adminPanel: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var currentNumberAdmin: UILabel!                       

    @IBAction func nextCurrent(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let database = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        database.child("current").observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

          self.currentNumberAdmin.text = snapshot.value as! String
          currentNumberAdmin += String(1)
        })

    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can convert and increase `currentNumberAdmin` correctly?

Comment: Why are you adding a string to a view? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is crashing because of this line: `currentNumberAdmin += String(1)`. You're attempting to add a String value to a UILabel value, which is invalid. You're literally telling the compiler to assign `currentNumberAdmin`, a UILabel, to the value of the expression of adding a UILabel to a String, which the compiler doesn't know how to do, hence the exception message.

It's not entirely clear why you're attempt to set the label's text twice: once with snapshot.value, and then again on the next line. If what you're trying to do is set the label's text to the snapshot value + 1, do something like this:

```
@IBAction func nextCurrent(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let database = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    database.child("current").observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

      var strVal = Int(self.currentNumberAdmin.text)!
      strVal += 1
      self.currentNumberAdmin.text = String(strVal)
    })

}
```

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that snapshot.value is attributed as Any?

Comment: When i try to cast it as an int i get this error: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'int' with an argument list of type '(Any?)'

Comment: @EliasKnudsen if you're just trying to increment the value of the text by 1 every time, you just need to cast the value back and forth each time. I've updated my example to reflect that. The one caveat is this will crash if currentNumberAdmin.text contains a non-numeric value. E.g. if the label contains "hi" it will crash, but if it contains "0" it will work as expected.

Comment: When i use the code you wrote it recommends to put a ! inside the parameters like this: "var strVal = Int(self.currentNumberAdmin.text!)!". When i run this it finds nil unexpectedly while unwrapping an optional value.

Comment: You either need to set the initial value of the label to 0 in interface builder, or you need to add a check in the code (probably safer) to make sure that value isn't empty, which means to test for the string "".